# How to get specific JSON data?

Tags: java, json, parsing

Hi I am trying to read JSON from an ReST API but Im getting a nullpointer exception because mycode is not correct.

I have a JSON that I am reading from looking like this :

```
processJSON({
"LocationList":{
  "noNamespaceSchemaLocation":"http://api.vasttrafik.se/v1/hafasRestLocation.xsd",
  "servertime":"16:13",
  "serverdate":"2013-03-22",
  "StopLocation":[{
    "name":"Brunnsparken, Göteborg",
    "lon":"11.967824",
    "lat":"57.706944",
    "id":"9021014001760000",
    "idx":"1"
    },{
    "name":"Brunnsgatan, Göteborg",
    "lon":"11.959455",
    "lat":"57.693766",
    "id":"9021014001745000",
    "idx":"4"
    },{
    "name":"Brunnslyckan, Lerum",
    "lon":"12.410219",
    "lat":"57.812073",
    "id":"9021014017260000",
    "idx":"5"
    },
```

Now I want the name from the JSON document depending on what the user inputs.

how do I do this with code?

My code that is wrong is like this :

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;

    public class JSONReader {

        private String jsonData = "";


        public String getJsonData(String location){


            try {

                    URL url = new     URL("http://api.vasttrafik.se/bin/rest.exe/v1/location.name?authKey=secret&format=json&jsonpCallback=processJSON&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(location, "UTF-8"));
                    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                    BufferedReader readJsonFile = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                    String temp = "";
                    while((temp = readJsonFile.readLine()) != null){
                            jsonData += temp;
                    }
                    readJsonFile.close();

                    System.out.println(jsonData);
                    return jsonData;

            }

            catch (IOException e) {

            }
            return null;
    }

       public void JSONParsing(){

                String location = Planner.getPlanner().getStartingLocation();
                JSONObject obj =(JSONObject)JSONValue.parse(getJsonData(location));

                //Set the text into the JList

                if (obj.containsValue(location));
                obj.get("name");
                }
    }
```

I want get the same name of the location out from the JSON as the user inputs.
How do I do this with code?

Comment: _I want get the same name of the location out from the JSON as the user inputs_ <-- what does that mean??

Comment: If the user picks a location it shall find that location from the JSON file

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are asking how to parse your `JSONObject` and get the corresponding values out of it that the user is interested in. Below is an example of how you can pull apart the `JSONObject` to create a `Map` whose key is the `String` id (since the name does not seem to be unique) and whose value is the whole `JSONObject`. You can use this map to lookup the input from the user and find the appropriate LLA if that's what you are interested in.

```
public Map<String, JSONObject> createLocationMap(JSONObject jsonObj){
    Map<String, JSONObject> nameToLocationMap = new HashMap<String, JSONObject>();
    JSONObject locationList = (JSONObject) jsonObj.get("LocationList");
    JSONArray array = (JSONArray) locationList.get("StopLocation");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        String name = (String) ((JSONObject) array.get(i)).get("id");
        nameToLocationMap.put(name, ((JSONObject)array.get(i)));
    }
    return nameToLocationMap;
}
```

You can tailor this method as you see fit. For example if you are interested in the relationship between the `id` and the `name` then you can create a similar method that uses those values instead of `id` and the entire `JSONObject'`. I hope that this helps~